# How to rewrite URL in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I noticed that Framework7's url is like this

`https://domain.com/signup.html#!/#geolocation`

Is there any way to make the urls cleaner if I'm looking at it as webapp and mobile app.

I can't see any documentation how to handle urls for webapps. I might have missed it or it's not documented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to have a cleaner look and depending by your needs you can:

1. choose an appropriate `pushStateSeparator` during app initialization.

   ```
   var myApp = new Framework7({
   pushState: true,
   pushStateSeparator: '#page/',
   // ... other parameters
   });
   ```
2. disable router and manage this by your own.

   ```
   var myApp = new Framework7({
   router: false,
   // ... other parameters
   });
   ```

More on this in each parameter description on [F7 Documentation](https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html).

Comment: Cool! Thanks I must have missed that section of the docu. I'll try it out. :)